# filtering list objects by multiple variable conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects that I need to pull values from and save to another list. If there are duplicate name values, I need to choose the entry that is closet to the provided effective date. I'm trying to do this with a number of if statements but it's a mess and isn't functioning as expected. I would imagine that there's a simpler way to do this using LINQ but I don't know how to filter out both conditions.

here is my object class

````
class ExcelMessageRows
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

 //Here is the code using nested if statements -


           List<ExcelMessageRows> compareRows = new List<ExcelMessageRows>();
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "1", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1997), Message = "a2" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "1", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2005), Message = "a3" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "1", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2015), Message = "a4" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "2", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1997), Message = "a5" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "3", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1998), Message = "a6" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "3", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2006), Message = "a7" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "4", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2015), Message = "a8" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "5", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1998), Message = "a9" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "6", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1999), Message = "a10" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "7", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/1997), Message = "a11" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "7", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2014), Message = "a12" });
            compareRows.Add(new ExcelMessageRows { Name = "7", Date = DateTime.FromOADate(12/1/2016), Message = "a13" });

            //SETTING AN EFFECTIVE DATE AND STATE
            DateTime effectiveDate = DateTime.Now;
            //FINAL LIST OF MESSAGES
            List<string> decMessages = new List<string>();

            int previousRow = 1;

            compareRows.OrderBy(x => x.Name); 

            foreach (ExcelMessageRows mRows in compareRows)
            {                
                if (mRows.Name.Equals(compareRows[previousRow - 1].Name))
                {
                    if (effectiveDate > mRows.Date 
                        && effectiveDate > compareRows[previousRow - 1].Date)
                    { 
                        decMessages.Add(mRows.Message);
                    }

                    if (effectiveDate < mRows.Date
                        && effectiveDate > compareRows[previousRow - 1].Date)
                    {
                        decMessages.Add(compareRows[previousRow - 1].Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    decMessages.Add(compareRows[previousRow - 1].Message);
                }
                previousRow++;
            }

            foreach (string mes in decMessages)
                Console.WriteLine(mes);
        }```
````

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do what you describe - it returns all three messages for `Name` "1", for example, and not the latest. BTW, note that `OrderBy` is a LINQ method that returns a new `IEnumerable`, _it does not sort the `List`_ passed in.

Comment: Also, your code for creating sample data doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will add the closest message per name to the list. always use linq with caution. short code doesnt mean short runtime complexity.

```
        var groups = compareRows.GroupBy(p => p.Name);
        var decMessages = new List<string>();
        foreach (var group in groups)
            decMessages.Add(group.OrderBy(p => Math.Abs(effectiveDate.Subtract(p.Date).TotalMilliseconds)).Last().Message);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. I'm also looking, for those rows with three identical names, to capture the listing before the effective date.i.e. so if there were dates 1998, 2005, and 2018 and the effective date was 2018. The list would add 2005. I need to get more experience with using LINQ. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is group by name so you can select the nearest of each group:

```
var decMessages = compareRows.GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                             .Select(rg => rg.OrderBy(r => effectiveDate-r.Date).First().Message)
                             .ToList();
```